# How to use scala trait with `self` reference?

Tags: scala

I saw some code write trait as following:

```
trait SelfAware { self: Self =>
 ....
}

class Self
val s = new Self with SelfAware // this is ok
println(s.self) // error happened

class X
new X with SelfAware // error happened here
```

I'd like to know why the error happened and how to use trait in this way?

Comment: I'd like to know why the error happened and how to use trait in this way?

Comment: I'm glad you ran into this error, I learned a bit more about traits because of it. :) It is especially interesting that you can specify restrictions in this way about what kinds of things the trait can be applied to.

Comment: Since this is the first time I run on this type of syntax I am wondering what is the difference between `trait SomeTrait { this: SomeType => .... }` and `trait SomeTrait extends SomeType { ... }` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error is occurring because you have constrained the type of the `this` reference (which you have named `self`) to be of type `Self`. When you say `new Self with SelfAware`, this is OK, because that object is of type `Self` like you asked. But when you say `new X with SelfAware`, there is no evidence that `X` is in any way a subtype of `Self`.

In your new object of type `X with SelfAware`, what would be the type of its `self` member? Well, it would not be of type `Self`, but of type `X`. But you have defined the trait `SelfAware` so that `self` must be of type `Self`, so you get a type error.

Answer (score 21):

I also found the answer here: http://markthomas.info/blog/?p=92

### Self Types

Ordered can be mixed in to any class; it doesn’t depend on any methods or fields of the class that it is mixed in to. Sometimes it’s useful for a trait to be able to use the fields or methods of a class it is mixed in to, this can be done by specifying a self type for the trait. A self type can be specified for a class or a trait as follows:

```
trait SpellChecker { self =>
  ...
}
```

self within the context of this trait will refer to this. Aliasing this is useful for nested classes or traits where it would otherwise be difficult to access a particular this. The syntax can be extended to specify a lower-bounds on this, when this is done the trait or class can use the features of this lower-bound class, so it can extend or modify its behaviour.

```
trait SpellChecker { self: RandomAccessSeq[char] =>
  ...
}
```

The compiler will check that any class in a hierarchy including SpellChecker is or extends RandomAccessSeq[char], so SpellChecker can now use the fields or methods of RandomAccessSeq[char]

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but does this mean that the SpellChecker trait cannot be mixed with anything else than a RandomAccessSeq or one of its children ? isn't this somehow a violation of the Liskov principle ?

Comment: @FrancisToth I think you are right on the money. This effectively makes `SpellChecker` only applicable in a subtree of a hierarchy with a root of `RandomAccessSeq[char]`. What's worse, when you actually use the syntax `SomeType extends SpellChecker`, there is no explicit indication that `SpellChecker` relies on this specialization of its `self` type. Even if `SomeType` is in the right hierarchy to be allowed to use `SpellChecker`, this might still be extremely mysterious to people who are new to specializing their own class by mixing in `SpellChecker`.

Answer (score 12):

To answer the other half of your question (why does `println(s.self)` produce an error?), that is because `self` is not a field of `SelfAware`. It can be used to define such fields, however:

```
trait SelfAware { self =>
  val me = self
}

class X
val x = new X with SelfAware
println(s.me)
```

Comment: so, given `val s = new Self with SelfAware`; doing `s.self` fails to compile since `s` is **not** a `Self`, but a `Self with SelfAware`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: no, it fails to compile because `self` is not a field of `Self`, nor of `SelfAware`. In my example above, I've bound `val me = self`, which makes the field `me` available to anything with the `SelfAware` trait.