# Get a class field from trait

Tags: scala

I have a trait:

```scala
trait A {
  /*Some methods*/
}
```

And I have a lot of classes:

```scala
class B(val argument: SomeClass) extends A {
  /*Some methods*/
}
```

I want to get an argument from trait. I can create method getArgument in each class and trait:

```scala
trait A {
  def getArgument: SomeClass
  /*Some methods*/
}
class B(val argument: SomeClass) extends A {
  def getArgument = argument
  /*Some methods*/
}
```

Or use reflection:

```scala
trait A {
  def getArgument = {
    val f =  this.getClass.getDeclaredField("argument")
    f.setAccessible(true)
    f.get(this).asInstanceOf[SomeClass]
  }
  /*Some methods*/
}
class B(val argument: SomeClass) extends A {
  /*Some methods*/
}
```

Are there any better ways to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have abstract vals:

```
trait A {
  val argument: SomeClass
}

class B(val argument: SomeClass) extends A
```

You need even not constraint it to be a val:

```
trait A {
  def argument: SomeClass
}

class B(val argument: SomeClass) extends A

class C extends A {
  def argument : SomeClass = ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but for sake of searchers...
You can define type of `this` and access its members:

```
class ArgContainer(val argument: SomeClass)

class B(argument: SomeClass) extends ArgContainer(argument) with A
class C(argument: SomeClass) extends ArgContainer(argument) with A

trait A {
  this: ArgContainer =>

  def print() = {
    println(this.argument)
  }
}
```

See more here [How to use scala trait with `self` reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291176/how-to-use-scala-trait-with-self-reference)