# What does it mean if trait starts with self: Actor

Tags: scala, function, traits

I don't quite a good Scala programmer and need some help with understanding syntax. Here is the [***trait***](https://github.com/levkhomich/akka-tracing/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/levkhomich/akka/tracing/ActorTracing.scala) I am struggling with:

```
trait ActorTracing extends AroundReceiveOverrideHack { self: Actor =>

  protected def serviceName: String =
    this.getClass.getSimpleName

  implicit def any2response[T](msg: T): ResponseTracingSupport[T] =
    new ResponseTracingSupport(msg)

  implicit lazy val trace: TracingExtensionImpl =
    TracingExtension(context.system)

  override protected final def aroundReceiveInt(receive: Receive, msg: Any): Unit =
    msg match {
      case ts: BaseTracingSupport if receive.isDefinedAt(msg) =>
        trace.start(ts, serviceName)
      case _ =>
    }
}
```

It seems that the traits' body starts with `Function1` literal. `self:Actor =>`... What would it mean here in this example?

Comment: May be duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291176/how-to-use-scala-trait-with-self-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It defines a dependency of the Actor class meaning that any class that extends `ActorTracing` should also extend `Actor`. This basically builds on the DI and the Cake pattern in Scala which is the idea of building layers up of software.

So in this example it is basically saying that `ActorTracing` cannot be used on anything that doesn't also extend `Actor`

Here is a really good article about this.
http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/

Comment: As note, "any trait that extends ActorTracing should also extend Actor" it's not correct, any `class` that extends that trait has to also extend `Actor`, `trait` don't necessarily have to.